# SQL 2012 - Query to return month number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to return the month number for a given date. For the current month, the month number would be 0. For the following month, the MonthNo would be 1. The previous month would be -1, 2 months ago would be -2. etc
So assuming today is 16 June 2020, see example data below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DateTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DateTest

CREATE TABLE #DateTest
(
DateTest Date
)

INSERT INTO #DateTest
VALUES
('23/08/2020'),
('14/06/2020'),
('01/06/2020'),
('15/05/2020'),
('01/05/2020'),
('18/01/2020') 

Select * FROM #DateTest
```

I would need to return the below:

```
Date          MonthNo
23/08/2020    2
14/06/2020    0
01/06/2020    0
15/05/2020    -1
01/05/2020    -1
18/01/2020    -5
```

Is there any way to return this info?

Comment: What's wrong with DateDiff?

Comment: Side note: You shouldn't use `dd/MM/yyyy` as a date format, since it's culture specific (try running this on Rextester, for instance, you'll get an error converting string to datetime). Instead, use one of the formats specified in ISO8601: `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyymmdd`. This way, you're safe in any culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like ordinary [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-previousversions), it should work for you:

```
SELECT 
  DateTest AS [Date],
  DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), DateTest) AS [MonthNo]
FROM #DateTest
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8cbe719b948782fc5d38eecc51ac744f)