# Geocode addresses contained in a SQL Server 2012 table - add a lat/lon

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, geocoding, geocode

I know this has been asked a few times in the distant past, but I couldn't find anything recent so please bear with me!

I need to geocode about 6,000 UK addresses stored in a SQL Server 2012 table. They are addresses for buildings in the UK, with a postcode and full address. I need to get the lat and lon values for all addresses where there is no lat/lon currently available.

So there is an initial 6000 or so addresses to geocode, and then I would need to do this every night for any new addresses that may also get added - maybe 15 to 20 on average

The addresses are stored in in this format - 3 columns of data:

```
Building name 
Street 
Post code
```

Street contains the whole building address excluding the building name and postcode Eg;

```
Afflecks Palace
52 Church Street, Manchester 
M4 1PW
```

I would like to end up with this:

```
Building name 
Street 
Post code 
Latitude
Longitude
```

So for the above example:

```
Afflecks Palace
52 Church Street, Manchester 
M4 1PW
53.482534
-2.236194
```

2 questions - is Bing Maps or Google Maps API best to use for this task? I read a few posts saying that Google Maps is not so good for geocoding UK addresses, but those posts were 5 to 7 years old, and older.

I am trying to follow the article here as it is the newest relevant one that I could find:

[Geocoding in SQL Server with the Bing Maps Locations API](https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/geocoding-in-sql-server-with-the-bing-maps-locations-api/)

I am at the stage of trying to create the assembly, but I get the below error in SSMS:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY failed because it could not open the physical file
'C:\Users\XXXX\source\repos\GeocodeSQLAddress\Geocode\bin\Debug\Geocode.dll': 3
(The system cannot find the path specified.).
```

I would also add that I have never done anything in Visual Studio before, or anything with DLLs, C#, or any languages like that. Im just trying to follow the article best I can

Cheers for all help

Edit: So I have now got this assembly working in SQL Server - thank you @Larnu. What would be the best way to use this assembly against a table of addresses, rather than just one address per the link above?

Comment: The SQL Server Service account should **not** have access to *your* User Documents (and it doesn't, that's why you can't create the Assembly). Put the file in a location that the SQL Server Service Account has access to.

Comment: DOH! Any idea where the best place to put this file would be on the SQL Server @Larnu ?

Comment: That depends on where your SQL Server has access to. I would suggest *somewhere* on the local machine, but after that is really up to up, as long as it's appropriate.

Comment: I found the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies - is it okay to put a new Assembly file here, or would that affect the SQL Server?

Comment: You might want to put it in a different folder, for custom assemblies

Comment: Ive never done anything like this before, ive only ever ran queries in SQL, so this is completely new to me, does a SQL Server install come with a default directory where custom assemblies are placed?

Comment: No, you would need to create one.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to run this assembly against multiple address records in one go, rather than one at a time as it currently does if I follow the article?

Comment: It would just be `SELECT dbo.Geocode({Parameters}) FROM dbo.YourTable;`, like any other scalar function.

Comment: Sorry ive never used a function before, I will try this tonight see how it goes

Comment: *"Sorry ive never used a function before,"* I actually doubt that, @Naz. `CAST`, `GETDATE`, `NEWID`, `DATEDIFF` (which you were given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62405289/2029983)) are all functions...

Comment: Whoops I meant created a function, not used a function